# How can I disable the keyboard backlight on an Alienware M14xR2?

Tags: alienware, keyboard-backlight

How do I turn on and off the keyboard backlights of an Alienware M14xR2 within Linux? Or, if possible, I'd like to completely disable the keyboard.

Comment: most of laptops do control the keyboard light option via bios... May be you can check entering to bios at start up

Comment: Please edit your post to add the Linux distro you use, and its release number (e.g., Kubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit, or 32-bit LXLE 12.04.2).

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

To disable the keyboard completely:

1. Run `xinput list`.
2. Find the device ID of your keyboard here (it shouldn't be hard).
3. Run `sudo xinput disable [device ID]`.

Comment: I tried it says unable to find device [id=3].

Comment: @hulkmad Take away the `[]`. I use those to connote a variable. Sorry for the confusion.